# Why is const auto not working with trailing return type? (Error C3551 in Visual Studio)

Tags: c++

Description of the error code:

> if a trailing return type is used then the leading return type shall be the single type-specifier 'auto' (not 'const auto')

Basically, this code snippet does not work:

```
const auto begin() const -> decltype(_data.begin()) { return _data.begin(); }
```

May I please know why this does not work? I am using MSVC 2019, Visual Studio 2019. Thank you!

Comment: It does not work because of what the error says... if you want to return a `const` instance of an iterator, then put the `const` with the rest of the trailing return type, i.e. _in the trailing bit_, after the `->` (doesn't matter if the `const` is before or after the type, as usual). But I don't know if there's much point though: most folk don't bother being that defensive to return `const` objects now AFAICT.

Comment: Are you wondering why the C++ specification says that `const auto` doesn't work? Or how to fix the error message you get?

Comment: @underscore_d I have tried it like so, but the error persists: `const auto begin()  ->const decltype(_data.begin()) { return _data.begin(); }`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am concerned with the latter, as the code was retrieved from a supposedly working package. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: @LeStarfish I meant to move the `const` from the start to after the `->`, not to copy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a function where the return type is specified after the parameters, `auto` is not a type specifier. It's just a token that tells the parser to start parsing a function (kinda).

However, `const auto` is a type placeholder for the return type of the function. That is, if you start a function declaration with `const auto`, you have already specified that the return type will be deduced. So you can't specify the return type after the parameters.

So put the `const` with the actual return type, not at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you. I marked this as the answer as it convinced me not to use the trailing return type. I needed 2 versions of the function (1 with const and 1 without).